# Removing extra quotation marks from a string

Tags: php, mysql, oop

so I have a lot of problematic values in my database.
There are two columns, one is email. Some emails are stored in this way **"foo@foobar.com**, the quotation mark at the starting is useless. I want that to be converted to **foo@foobar.com**.
Similarly, there's another field known as company, which has data like this **stackoverflow"**, the quotation mark at the ending needs to be removed as well.

I have written this code, but for some reason this doesn't removes the quotation marks.
What am I doing wrong ?
Any suggestions are welcome.

```
global $conn;
        try
        {
            $statement= $conn->query("SELECT * from emails");
            $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            while($rows = $statement->fetch())
            {
                $email=$rows['emailid'];
                $company=$rows['company'];
                $len = strlen($company);
                if($email{0} == '"')
                {
                    //problem at start
                    //fix there.
                    $updated = substr($email, 1);
                    //now update
                    try
                    {
                        $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE emails set emailid = :email where indexid = :indexid");
                        $statement->bindParam(':email',$updated);
                        $statement->bindParam(':indexid',$row['indexid']);
                        $statement->execute();
                        $statement->closeCursor();
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                    }
                }
                elseif($company{$len-1} == '"')
                {
                    $updated = substr($company, 0, -1);
                    //now update
                    try
                    {
                        $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE emails set company = :company where indexid = :indexid");
                        $statement->bindParam(':company',$updated);
                        $statement->bindParam(':indexid',$row['indexid']);
                        $statement->execute();
                        $statement->closeCursor();
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "";
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: Why not just `str_replace`?

Comment: You're returning true inside the if statement; it's only ever going to run once, as the return will terminate the loop. If that's not the problem - add some debugging. Is the SQL statement running? Is it picking up the right entries? Are your substr calls working? Figure out which part isn't working.

Comment: you can remove the unwanted strings once for over in the DB using mysql `replace` function

Comment: @andrewsi
I removed the return true from if and else and it's working fine.
However, it only fixes one entry once. Doesn't fixes all at once. Suppose there are 3 errors, then I need to run the script for 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use trim:

```
trim($text, " \"'");
```

it's remove spaces and quotes from start and end of `text` variable